# ui4j library can not run on ubuntu VM with out a browser

Tags: java, web-scraping

I created a scraping program in java using the ui4j library, but it turns out that I have to run it on a VM where a browser is not present.

Is there a way around it? Do  I have to install a browser?

if yes do I need a proper one or a text based browser can do? (I don't think so, but i am asking just in case.)

Thanks, Ilias

EDIT:

This is the error i am getting from the VM. From the line saying Unable to open DISPLAY, i assumed there was a problem with the browser. What might b the problem then?

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to open DISPLAY
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.<init>(GtkApplication.java:68)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.createApplication(GtkPlatform Factory.java:41)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.run(Application.java:146)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java: 263)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:211)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:675)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:695)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(LauncherImpl.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$29/1893654604.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: RTFM for ui4j. ui4j depends on javafx which is installed via oracle java 8. javafx brings everything what is needed to build a browser. That's meant with JavaFx WebKit Engine. So to answer your question: You won't need a browser installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that i had to enable the Headless Mode of the ui4j as mentioned on the readme [file](https://github.com/ui4j/ui4j#headless-mode).